# Enable/disable not working in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

I have this radio-button. When **no** is checked, the next top radio buttons must be disabled and unchecked (this works). When the user clicks **yes**, the next two radio buttons should be enabled and clickable. Here is the problem - by clicking **yes** the buttons are still not clickable. I made something wrong. My code follows. Your help is appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".blind-7").attr('disabled', true);
 $(".blind-8").attr('disabled', true);
 $(".nebel-3").css('opacity', '0.1');
 
 $("form input:radio").change(function() {
  if ($('#033b').is(':checked')) {
   $(".blind-7, .blind-8").attr('disabled', true);
   $(".blind-7").prop('checked', false);
   $(".blind-8").prop('checked', false);
   $(".nebel-3").css('opacity', '0.1');
  }
  else if ($('#033a').is(':checked')) {
   $(".blind-7, .blind-8").attr('disabled', false);
   $(".nebel-3").css('opacity', '1');
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.nebel {
 color: black;
 background: #F9CA83;
}

.nebel-3 {
 color: black;
 background: #F9CA83;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <label class="nebel" for="033">click here</label>
    <input id="033b" type="radio" name="question" value="0"checked> <label for="033b">no</label>
    <input id="033a" type="radio" name="question" value="1"> <label for="033a">yes</label>

    <label class="nebel-3" for="034">type</label>
    <input id="034b" class="blind-8" type="radio" name="type" value="0" > <label for="034b">A</label>
    <input id="034a" class="blind-7" type="radio" name="type" value="1"> <label for="034a">B</label><br />

    <label class="nebel-3" for="035">time</label>
    <input id="035b" class="blind-8" type="radio" name="time" value="0" > <label for="035b">acute</label>
    <input id="035a" class="blind-7" type="radio" name="time" value="1"> <label for="035a">chronic</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no parent `form` in the selector.

Change `$("form input:radio")` to `$("input:radio")`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".blind-7").attr('disabled', true);
 $(".blind-8").attr('disabled', true);
 $(".nebel-3").css('opacity', '0.1');

 $("input:radio").change(function() {
  if ($('#033b').is(':checked'))
  {
   $(".blind-7, .blind-8").attr('disabled', true);
   $(".blind-7").prop('checked', false);
   $(".blind-8").prop('checked', false);
   $(".nebel-3").css('opacity', '0.1');
  }
  else if ($('#033a').is(':checked'))
  {
   $(".blind-7, .blind-8").attr('disabled', false);
   $(".nebel-3").css('opacity', '1');
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.nebel {
 color: black;
 background:#F9CA83;
}

.nebel-3 {
 color: black;
 background:#F9CA83;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="nebel" for="033">click here</label>
<input id="033b" type="radio" name="question" value="0"checked> <label for="033b">no</label>
<input id="033a" type="radio" name="question" value="1"> <label for="033a">yes</label>


<label class="nebel-3" for="034">preop_ad_type_a</label>
<input id="034b" class="blind-8" type="radio" name="type" value="0" > <label for="034b">A</label>
<input id="034a" class="blind-7" type="radio" name="type" value="1"> <label for="034a">B</label><br />

<label class="nebel-3" for="035">preop_ad_type_b</label>
<input id="035b" class="blind-8" type="radio" name="time" value="0" > <label for="035b">acute</label>
<input id="035a" class="blind-7" type="radio" name="time" value="1"> <label for="035a">chronic</label>
```

Comment: It's not working. In my original code this radio buttons are embedded in fieldset in a form. Still not working with or without form :(

Comment: Maybe you should post the whole HTML to see what's going on. :/

Comment: I'll edit my code

Comment: I don't get it. Here all works and in my code it's not...

Comment: Is this from the original code?
 $(form "input:radio").change(function() {

Comment: Check in the Developer Tools's console if there's any JS error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163289/discussion-between-adrian-and-pussyfer).

Comment: I found the problem - there was another radio button with the same id and that’s why the one I used didn’t worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just modify this `$("form input:radio")`
to this `$("input:radio")` because you don't have a form tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".blind-7").attr('disabled', true);
    $(".blind-8").attr('disabled', true);
    $(".nebel-3").css('opacity', '0.1');

    $("input:radio").change(function() {
        if ($('#033b').is(':checked')) {
            $(".blind-7, .blind-8").attr('disabled', true);
            $(".blind-7").prop('checked', false);
            $(".blind-8").prop('checked', false);
            $(".nebel-3").css('opacity', '0.1');
        }
        else if ($('#033a').is(':checked')) {
            $(".blind-7, .blind-8").attr('disabled', false);
            $(".nebel-3").css('opacity', '1');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.nebel {
    color: black;
    background: #F9CA83;
}

.nebel-3 {
    color: black;
    background: #F9CA83;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>DOM Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label class="nebel" for="033">click here</label>
    <input id="033b" type="radio" name="question" value="0"checked> <label for="033b">no</label>
    <input id="033a" type="radio" name="question" value="1"> <label for="033a">yes</label>

    <label class="nebel-3" for="034">preop_ad_type_a</label>
    <input id="034b" class="blind-8" type="radio" name="type" value="0" > <label for="034b">A</label>
    <input id="034a" class="blind-7" type="radio" name="type" value="1"> <label for="034a">B</label><br />

    <label class="nebel-3" for="035">preop_ad_type_b</label>
    <input id="035b" class="blind-8" type="radio" name="time" value="0" > <label for="035b">acute</label>
    <input id="035a" class="blind-7" type="radio" name="time" value="1"> <label for="035a">chronic</label>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `$("form input:radio").change` is trying to attach a change listener to an input of type radio, inside of a form.

This isn't working because you dont have `<form>` tags around your radio buttons. It will work if you add `<form>` tags like this:

```
<form>
<label class="nebel" for="033">click here</label>
<input id="033b" type="radio" name="question" value="0"checked> <label for="033b">no</label>
<input id="033a" type="radio" name="question" value="1"> <label for="033a">yes</label>


<label class="nebel-3" for="034">preop_ad_type_a</label>
<input id="034b" class="blind-8" type="radio" name="type" value="0" > <label for="034b">A</label>
<input id="034a" class="blind-7" type="radio" name="type" value="1"> <label for="034a">B</label><br />

<label class="nebel-3" for="035">preop_ad_type_b</label>
<input id="035b" class="blind-8" type="radio" name="time" value="0" > <label for="035b">acute</label>
<input id="035a" class="blind-7" type="radio" name="time" value="1"> <label for="035a">chronic</label>
</form>`
```

Alternatively, you could update the line where you are attaching your change listener to read:
`$("input:radio").change`

Either of these should work

Answer (score -1):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".blind-7").attr('disabled', true);
  $(".blind-8").attr('disabled', true);
  $(".nebel-3").css('opacity', '0.1');
 
$("input:radio").change(function() {
  if ($('#033b').is(':checked')) {
  $(".blind-7, .blind-8").attr('disabled', true);
  $(".blind-7").prop('checked', false);
  $(".blind-8").prop('checked', false);
  $(".nebel-3").css('opacity', '0.1');
}
else if ($('#033a').is(':checked')) {
 $(".blind-7, .blind-8").attr('disabled', false);
 $(".nebel-3").css('opacity', '1');
}
  });
});
```

```css
.nebel {
  color: black;
  background:#F9CA83;
}

.nebel-3 {
  color: black;
  background:#F9CA83;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <label class="nebel" for="033">click here</label>
    <input id="033b" type="radio" name="question" value="0"checked> <label for="033b">no</label>
    <input id="033a" type="radio" name="question" value="1"> <label for="033a">yes</label>


    <label class="nebel-3" for="034">type/label>
    <input id="034b" class="blind-8" type="radio" name="type" value="0" > <label for="034b">A</label>
    <input id="034a" class="blind-7" type="radio" name="type" value="1"> <label for="034a">B</label><br />

    <label class="nebel-3" for="035">time</label>
    <input id="035b" class="blind-8" type="radio" name="time" value="0" > <label for="035b">acute</label>
    <input id="035a" class="blind-7" type="radio" name="time" value="1"> <label for="035a">chronic</label>
```